# How to horizontally align items with equations in multicols package

Tags: horizontal-alignment, enumerate, multicol

I am using the multicols package in combination with enumerate environment, with equations in each item. Each item is aligned horizontally with its equation, and I like that. Whay I dont like is that items are not aligned horizontally between them. There a solution for align items horizontally between them, with this package, or another one?

This is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{4}
\begin{enumerate}
\item $\displaystyle \frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{x}}$
\item $\displaystyle \frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{x}}$
\item $\displaystyle 1+x$
\item $\displaystyle 1+x$
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

May be you are safe with `tasks`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[more]{tasks}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tasks}[style=enumerate](4)
  \task $\displaystyle \frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{x}}$
  \task $\displaystyle \frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{x}}$
  \task $\displaystyle 1+x$
  \task $\displaystyle 1+x$
  \end{tasks}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or with `enumitem`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate*}[itemjoin=\hfill]
\item $\displaystyle \frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{x}}$
\item $\displaystyle \frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{x}}$
\item $\displaystyle 1+x$
\item $\displaystyle 1+x$
\end{enumerate*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is the first time I heard about tasks package, and this is exactly I want. All the others solutions also are good, but this one solves my problem in a better way.

Comment: @Harish Kumar With tasks, Can I get numberate has the form 1) 2) ...?

Comment: @minthao_2011: Add `,counter-format=tsk)` to the options.

Answer (score 8):

This numbers horizontally rather than in columns, but doesn't need any packages:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\newcommand\z[1]{%
\baselineskip3\normalbaselineskip
\makebox[.25\textwidth][l]{%
\refstepcounter{enumi}%
\makebox[2em][l]{\theenumi.}%
$\displaystyle#1$}\linebreak[0]\hfill\ignorespaces}

\begin{document}


\begin{center}
\z{\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{x}}}
\z{\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{x}}}
\z{1+x}
\z{1+x}
\z{\frac{19}{1+\frac{1}{xkkk}}}
\z{\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{x}}}
\z{\frac{1+x}{2}}
\z{z+x}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, the code works perfect, but I have several sistems of equations (in line), with different number of equations in the same document, so I need to modify the code with different name in the same document.

Comment: you only need to modify the code if you want a different number of columns you can use `\newenvironment` to make yourself an environment that sets `\setcounter{enumi}{0}` then does the above `center` if you need different number of columns make that `#1` and replace `.25\textwidth` by `\dimexpr\textwidth/#1`