# Defining an environment for aligning elements in a table and labeling them alphabetically

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, environments

I'd like to automate this process in an environment as far as possible:

```
\documentclass[12pt,ngerman]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tabular}{llllll}
  \textbf{a)}  $a^{-3}+b^{7}$ &~
  \textbf{b)}  $a^{-3}+b^{7}$ &~
  \textbf{c)}  $a^{-3}+b^{7}$ &~
  \textbf{d)}  $a^{-3}+b^{7}$ &~
  \textbf{e)}  $a^{-3}+b^{7}$ &~
  \textbf{f)}  $a^{-3}+b^{7}$ \\    

  \textbf{g)}  $a^{-3}+b^{7}$ &~
  \textbf{h)}  $a^{-3}+b^{7}$ &~
  \textbf{i)}  $a^{-3}+b^{7}$ &~
  \textbf{j)}  $a^{-3}+b^{7}$ &~
  \textbf{k)}  $a^{-3}+b^{7}$ &~
  \textbf{l)}  $a^{-3}+b^{7}$ \\    
 \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

- For every new element there is an automated numeration ( a); b); c); etc.)
- The number of elements in one row is specified once or (even better) dependent on the elements that fit in one row.
- It is only necessary to add items (maybe with `/additem #1` or separated by semicolon or something) In this case `$a^{-3}+b^{7}$` is an item

It does not have to be in a table if there is a better solution.
It is important to me that

- The spaces are the same
- That is an extra space between each element (I did it with `&~`)
- The ’numbering’ is underneath itself / vertically aligned

---

Edit: This is a try without tabular (thanks to @David Carlisle)

```
\documentclass[12pt,ngerman]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}

\newcommand\z[2][0.25]{%
\noindent \baselineskip1.5\normalbaselineskip
\makebox[#1\textwidth][l]{%
\refstepcounter{enumi}%
\makebox[1.42em][l]{\alph{enumi})}%
$\displaystyle#2$}\linebreak[0]\hfill\ignorespaces}

\begin{document}
 \z[0.25]{ax^2+bx+c}
 \z[0.25]{ax^2+bx+c}   
 \z[0.25]{ax^2+bx+c}   
 \z[0.25]{ax^2+bx+c}   
 \z[0.25]{ax^2+bx+c}
 \z[0.25]{ax^2+bx+c}   
 \z[0.25]{ax^2+bx+c}   
 \z[0.25]{ax^2+bx+c}
\end{document}
```

- the `\hfill` prevents a horizontal left alignment and spreads the elements out evenly if there are not enough to fill the row
- I need to specify the rows for every element: e.g. `\z[0.25]{ax^2+bx+c}` for four elements per row
- I still need to reset the counter manually; it is **no enumerate or environment**

Maybe something with `\newlist`?
Awesome would be:

```
\begin{z}[0.25] % 4 items per row
 \item abcdef
 \item abcdef
 \item abcdef
\end{z}
```

---

*Edit: I provided compilable code thanks to cfr*

Comment: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/214314/how-to-horizontally-align-items-with-equations-in-multicols-package/214317#214317 for one approach

Comment: Please provide compilable code as it is is much more useful than mere fragments. It is not easy, right now, for me to understand your question. Compiling might help, but I'd have to mess around putting bits together. And then I might find I couldn't help or still didn't understand. So....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this is what OP wants or if it's a little bit overkill, but with `tcbraster` (from `tcolorbox`) is possible to do:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newenvironment{myitemize}%
{\begin{tcbitemize}[raster columns=4, raster equal height=rows, title={\thetcbrasternum}, attach title to upper={)\quad}, coltitle=black, empty, size=minimal]}
{\end{tcbitemize}}

\begin{document}
\begin{myitemize}
\tcbitem $a^{-3}+b^{7}$
\tcbitem $a^{-3}+b^{7}$
\tcbitem $a^{-3}+b^{7}$
\tcbitem $a^{-3}+b^{7}$
\tcbitem $a^{-3}+b^{7}$
\tcbitem $a^{-3}+b^{7}$
\tcbitem $a^{-3}+b^{7}$
\tcbitem $a^{-3}+b^{7}$
\tcbitem $a^{-3}+b^{7}$
\end{myitemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It doesn't compute number of columns, it's a parameter. All columns have same width, and all rows have same height with option `raster equal height=rows`.

Answer (score 1):

Modifying @Ignasi answer did a pretty good job:

```
\documentclass[12pt,ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newenvironment{myitemize}[1][4]%
{\begin{tcbitemize}[raster columns=#1, raster equal height=rows, title={\refstepcounter{enumi} \alph{enumi}}, attach title to upper={)\quad}, coltitle=black, empty, size=minimal]}
{\end{tcbitemize}\setcounter{enumi}{0}}


\begin{document}
\begin{myitemize}[3]
\tcbitem $a^{-3}+b^{7}$
\tcbitem $a^{-3}+b^{7}$
\tcbitem $a^{-3}+b^{7}$
\tcbitem $a^{-3}+b^{7}$
\tcbitem $a^{-3}+b^{7}$
\tcbitem $a^{-3}+b^{7}$
\tcbitem $a^{-3}+b^{7}$
\tcbitem $a^{-3}+b^{7}$
\tcbitem $a^{-3}+b^{7}$
\tcbitem $a^{-3}+b^{7}$
\end{myitemize}
~\\
\begin{myitemize}
\tcbitem $a^{-3}+b^{7}$
\tcbitem $a^{-3}+b^{7}$
\tcbitem $a^{-3}+b^{7}$
\tcbitem $a^{-3}+b^{7}$
\tcbitem $a^{-3}+b^{7}$
\tcbitem $a^{-3}+b^{7}$
\tcbitem $a^{-3}+b^{7}$
\tcbitem $a^{-3}+b^{7}$
\tcbitem $a^{-3}+b^{7}$
\tcbitem $a^{-3}+b^{7}$
\end{myitemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]