# Custom horizontal alignment in multicols environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, enumerate, multicol

If I utilize the two columns of multicols for my Kurdish sequence of numbers, it arranges the items in column like the following figure:

[image]
But I want to arrange the items in rows splitted by some columns (two columns in this case) alike the following figure:

[image]
And for the case of "three columns", the output would be alike the following figure:

[image]
How may I achieve the functionality? And I don't want to use the sequence of the following commands:

```
\begin{multicols}{2}‎
\begin{enumerate}[$1)$,noitemsep]
\item ‎
Yek
\item ‎
Du
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}‎
```

Instead, I want to specify the split count of the columns and then have the items arranged in the desired arrangement automatically. For the record, I've check [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/214317/71461) post, but it's too generalized.

Comment: `enumerate` isn't the right tool for this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `enumerate` environment is designed to enumerate downwards, not from left to right.

There are some packages for this, e.g. `paralist` or the sophisticated `task` package.

E.g. say `\begin{task}(2)` etc. for 2 columns, the `\task` command does what `\item` does for `enumerate`.

The `counter-format=tsk[1])` option will use arabic numbers with a closing `)`, the `label-width` and `label-align` options are self-explanatory (in my point of view).

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\MYNUMOFCOLUMNS{2}

\usepackage{tasks}
\begin{document}
\begin{tasks}[counter-format=tsk[1]),label-width={3ex},label-align=right](\MYNUMOFCOLUMNS)
\task Yek
\task Du
\task Se
\task Chuar
\task Penj
\task Shash
\task Havt
\task Hasht
\task Noh
\task Dah
\end{tasks}

\def\MYNUMOFCOLUMNS{3}

\begin{tasks}[counter-format=tsk[1]),label-width={3ex},label-align=right](\MYNUMOFCOLUMNS)
\task Yek
\task Du
\task Se
\task Chuar
\task Penj
\task Shash
\task Havt
\task Hasht
\task Noh
\task Dah
\end{tasks}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: My problem solved with your last edit, tnx :)