# Overlapping \part labels when using mulitple multicols environments in a \question (exam.cls)

Tags: multicol, exam

I am creating an answer key booklet using `exam.cls` for a question sheet that I had made for some students.

Along with that, I've used the `multicol` package to create a 2-column structure within a question that is composed of multiple parts. To be more specific, I've used 3 `multicols` environments (as seen in the code further below), and my reason for this is so that the labels are ordered **horizontally** and **not vertically**. What I mean by horizontally is having (a), (c), (e) on the left side and (b), (d), (f) on the right so that **(a) and (b) are on the same line, (c) and (d) together on the next and so on** (what the screenshot below would have looked like had the letters not overlapped); which is contrary to the vertical-style labelling where (a), (b), (c) are in the left column and (d), (e), (f) in the right. I've been trying to achieve this horizontal-style labelling, but I am faced with the issue of the part letters being in the wrong places:

### [image: Picture of letters being in the wrong place]

As you can see, part (c) and (e) are placed at the positions of (d) and (f) respectively, causing quite a mess. I would like to avoid repeating the question's original text (from the question sheet) after `\question` as I want (a) and (b) to be in-line with the question number.
Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{exam}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}
    \begin{questions}
        \question
            \begin{parts}
                \begin{multicols}{2}
                    \part answer
                    \part answer
                \end{multicols}
                \begin{multicols}{2}
                    \part answer
                    \part answer
                \end{multicols}
                \begin{multicols}{2}
                    \part answer
                    \part answer
                \end{multicols}
            \end{parts}
    \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

I am aware that placing the `\part` commands in a single `multicols` environment fixes the issue of overlapping letters, but this causes the labelling of the letters to be vertical and not horizontal. I also understand that the `parts` environment is used as the text for `\question`, but I can't understand why the output appears as such. How can I modify my code to fix this problem? And is using `exam.cls` inappropriate for this purpose?

Comment: Put all the `\part`s in one `multicols` environment.

Comment: @JesseopdenBrouw Thanks for an answer. That does fix the overlapping labels issue, but it makes the order of the `\part` letters go down vertically i.e. (a), (b), (c) in the left column and (d), (e), (f) in the right. I'd prefer for them to be labelled horizontally with (a), (c), (e) in the left and (b), (d), (f) in the right, which is why I created 3 `\multicols` environment. Is there any way to achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/308289/custom-horizontal-alignment-in-multicols-environment

Comment: @JesseopdenBrouw Thanks! The `task` package works great and suits my needs. Kudos to you.